# CentOs server working eviroment system/convension

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, virtualbox

This probably will be taken as a subjective question. But it is not. I am not asking for "Best" method, but only if I am breaking a huge DON'T DOs, or any convensions with following work-environment setup I just created only for dev-enviroment.

I am on Win 7, running VirtualBox 4.3.10 which has CentOS 6.5 minimal running in it with NAT Adapter. I have installed Guest Additions, PHP-FPM, Nginx, PHP-CLI (For running Composer)...

I am sharing my entire `E://` drive, so I can edit my projects directly from CentOS. I have changed nginx's public directory from `usr/share/nginx/html` to `www/var/public_html` Since I have mounted the var folder.

I did most of these settings without any reference, so I would like to know if I am doing something insane.

Comment: Did you consider installing a Linux distribution really on your laptop (without any virtual machine)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Funny I was about to ask that. That would mean I have to use Win7 as guest OS right. I think I'll do that, since now I will be using Linux more than I will be using Windows. Thanks. Others ?

Comment: No, I did not imply using Win7 (except if you play games). Just install Linux and use it. I never used Windows myself (using Linux since 1994, and Unix since 1987).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Nope. I don't play games, I just imagined there might be cases where there is something I need that only runs on windows but not in Linux. It'll probably be easier said than done, but I will backup my stuff and try to install linux at-least as a dual host first.